# Fetch values from column and split

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fetch names from table where

Table

```
Id        Name 
1         John Doe
2         Tom Cruise
3         Christopher Ashton Kutcher
4         Mel Gibson
5         David Jude Law
6         Brad Pitt
```

My approach is

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1) AS FirstName,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1) AS LastName,
FROM Table
```

But In above table there are some names having middle names too so with my approach I'm missing the First name, e.g for name `Christopher Ashton Kutcher` I'm getting `Ashton Kutcher` as output.

Note: It doesn't matter if `LastName` will have middle name too in output as long as I get `FirstName` too.

So what will be the work around?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What RDBMs are you using?

Comment: I think it's MySQL...

Comment: looks like you are using `MySQL`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I tagged the question wrong, it's `MySQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't care if middle name is mixed up with last name and you are splitting on `' '`, this should work.

```
select substring(name, 1, instr(name,' ')-1) as first_name,
       replace(name, substring(name, 1, instr(name,' ')-1), '') as last_name
from table;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da7a8e/1)

Comment: With the above solution, for `Christopher Ashton Kutcher` I'm getting this `Christopher Ashton Kutcher Ashton Kutcher` as output and for `Tom Cruise` getting this `Tom Cruise Cruise` as output

Comment: added a fiddle.please check

Comment: i have my own fiddle live working on site and if i replace this `substring(name, 1, instr(name,' ')-1) as first_name` with this `SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', 1) AS first_name` and for last name i used the code in your answer `replace(name, substring(name, 1, instr(name,' ')-1), '') as last_name` and It worked

Comment: I checked in the fiddle too and both working, your solution and with my changes too. thanks for the answer and help. +1